# ansible handler only runs once when notified from parameterized role

Tags: linux, ansible, upstart

I have an ansible playbook for some init services that are broadly similar with a few tweaks. In the top-level playbook, I include the role twice, like

```
   roles:
     - {role: "my-service", service: webserver}
     - {role: "my-service", service: scheduler}
```

the my-service role has tasks, which write init scripts, and handlers, which (re)start the service. `tasks/main.yml` looks like this:

```
- name: setup init scripts
  template: src=../../service-common/templates/my-service.conf dest=/etc/init/my-{{ service }}.conf
  notify:
    - restart my service
```

and `handlers/main.yml` has this content:

```
- name: restart my services
  service: name=my-{{ service }} state=restarted
```

But after the playbook runs, we're left with only the `webserver` service running, and the scheduler is `stop/waiting`. How can I make the handler see these as two separate notifications to be handled?

Comment: Bruce already explained the problem. For a solution you might have a look at this github issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4853 - Don't know if this now is possible or not. The last comment was a user tested it and it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#handlers) states:

> Handlers are lists of tasks, not really any different from regular tasks, that are referenced by a globally unique name.

So it doesn't make use of any parameters, variables, etc. when determining when/how to invoke a handler. Only the name is used.